# why is the powershell i can open from the run box not the same thing i can open from the start menu?

Tags: command-line, powershell, run-dialog

If I `WinKey + R` to open the run box and type `powershell` it works to some extent as it opens up a command line box. However, this windows doesn't behave like the powershell I can open from `Start > All Programs > Accessories > Windows PowerShell`. It's the wrong colour, and I can't highlight text the same way I can in my Start Menu powershell.

Why would these be different? Why would my 'Run' powershell not work the same way as my 'start' powershell? And how can I make it so they do?

Running Win7 Home Premium, but reproduced the problem on several different editions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access PowerShell from <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, you are running **powerhshell.exe** directly with the default settings. You change these default settings by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> while PowerShell is running.

When you access PowerShell from the Start Menu, you are launching a shortcut to powershell.exe that has pre-defined view settings already configured. To modify these settings, right-click the Start Menu shortcut, and select **Properties**. You can adjust the default view settings for PowerShell when launched specifically by this shortcut in the **Options**, **Font**, **Layout**, and **Color** tabs.

To answer **why** is fairly subjective. Most users likely access PowerShell from the Run... menu and can quickly set up their own default view options from a clean slate. For the less-frequent users who access PowerShell from the Start Menu, Microsoft provides some popular/common view settings to help get people started.